# Android View dismiss animation in wrong direction

Tags: android, android-animation, swipe

I'm currently dismissing a view on the bottom of the screen when the user swipes on it. The issue is that when you swipe right, the dismissal animation looks correct (it goes in the direction of the right swipe).

However, when you swipe left, the animation still goes in the direction of a right swipe.

The goal is to allow swipes in either direction.

In our own codebase we've never defined that the dismissal animation will go to the right. This is simply the way it is by default and I can't find anything in the SwipeDismissBehavior docs (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/SwipeDismissBehavior) that change that.

Here's just a quick snippet of what the code block looks like. I was hoping for some sort of setSwipeAnimationDirection() method or something. Or even have the animation follow the swipe direction by default but this doesn't seem to be the case.

```
private fun initSwipeBehavior(view: View) {
        val swipe = DragAwareSwipeDismissBehavior()
        swipe.setSwipeDirection(SwipeDismissBehavior.SWIPE_DIRECTION_END_TO_START)
        swipe.setListener(object : SwipeDismissBehavior.OnDismissListener {
            override fun onDismiss(view: View) {
                viewModel.dismiss(true)

                //set the alpha value back to 1.0f so that mini player shows up the next time
                //it needs to be shown
                view.alpha = 1.0f
            }

            override fun onDragStateChanged(state: Int) {}
        })

        val coordinatorParams = view.layoutParams as LayoutParams
        coordinatorParams.behavior = swipe
    }
```

Here's an example of what this looks like. https://www.androhub.com/swipe-dismiss-cardview-with-coordinator-layout/

This isn't my video but at 15 seconds you can clearly see the user swipes from right to left but the card dismissal animation goes from left to right

Answer (score 0):

Omar, here you can find the documentation for SwipeDismissBehavior's constants
https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/behavior/SwipeDismissBehavior#swipe_direction_end_to_start
SWIPE_DIRECTION_END_TO_START - Swipe direction that only allows swiping in the direction of end-to-start. That is right-to-left in LTR or left-to-right in RTL.
For your goal (swipe in any direction), maybe you have to use SWIPE_DIRECTION_ANY. :)